# Can a Flash Ad ( on Google Content Network ) Read the CSS Colors of Page?

Tags: css, flash, ads

Is it possible for a Flash Banner to read the CSS values from its host page?

Comment: Art, welcome to StackOverflow. Please ask each question separately. Formatting counts here. Leave comments in the comments area.

Comment: perhaps like this?  1) load the same html the swf is loaded in
2) regex css link
3) load css link
4) get a tag property

Answer (score 0):

Flash can call ExternalInterface, from there you have access to anything you can do in javascript.  You won't be able to guarantee any sort of framework on the page (like jQuery), so you'll have to stick with DOM calls...

Now, the amount of access that Javascript will have is a different question, as it depends on the ad network and how the files are embedded in the page.

Comment: is there a clever way to get/read the host Page's CSS bg color and a:link color properties via flash? I want the banner to change color based on the page's color. thanks